# Project tests fail when injecting a service in a MapStruct mapper

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a MapStruct mapper where I inject a service with a setter in the following way. The project compiles and works fine, until I try to run some project tests (not test related to this mapping), when an error occurs. I wonder if I have to configure anything extra for this case:

My mapper:

```
public abstract class MyMapper {

private MyService myService;

@Autowired
    public final void setMyService(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
    
...

}
```

The error message:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myMapperImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBmdMappingService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '***.MyService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: can you update the question and show the `MyService` class?  is it annotated with `@Service` or declared as a bean?

Comment: Also, what does your project file (Maven POM, Gradle file, whatever) look like?